# Accessing Global std::map values from a Global function in VS Debugger crashes the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdmap

I have several definitions like below:

```
class guid_typ;

static const guid_typ one {1};
static const char* sOne = "One Item";

static const guid_typ two {2};
static const char* sTwo = "Two Item";
...
```

**My requirements**:

1. While debugging, when I am at a break point, I want to be able to identify *one* by its name, *sOne*, in the watch window atleast.
2. For logging at runtime, when a function receives object *one*, I want to log say, *sOne* is received
3. One place(source file) where such mapping exists, and it is part of a DLL.

**My Restrictions**:

- I cannot change the type *guid_typ*
- I cannot wrap the type, *guid_typ* to create a new type say, *my_guid_typ*. This will be my preferred way but this type is used in at least 1000 sources, if not more. So I do not want to attempt it now. The integration effort is tremendous.

**My Implementation**:

I did the following to fulfill both the requirements

```
std::map<unsigned int, const char*>& GetRpmItemMap()
{
  static std::map<unsigned int, const char*> rimap = 
      {
        { 1, "One" },
        { 2, "Two" },
        { 3, "Three" },
        { 4, "Four" },
        { 5, "Five" },
      };

  return rimap;
}

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) const char* RI_NAME(unsigned int in)
{
  const char* val = [&]() {
    auto& m = GetRpmItemMap();
    auto it = m.find(in);
    if (it == m.end())
      return "Nothing found";
    else
      return it->second;
  }();
  return val;
}
```

**Current state**:

I am able to call this global function in the VS debugger watch window. It is not elegant but it works.

```
GetItemName(1)  returns "One"
definitions.dll!GetItemName(4)  returns "Four"
```

But every once in a while I see that it crashes in the std::map implementation. And this is what puzzles me, since I am only reading the map.

**Question**:

- Why is it crashing ? What am I missing here ?
- What would be your preferred approach given my requirements and
  restrictions ?

Comment: 1) Because it's likely there's some undefined behavior somewhere in your code that ends up corrupting the memory and scribbling all over this map, with random junk. 2) If all enumerated values were simply numbered starting with 1 or 0, I'd use a vector instead of a map.

Comment: 1. No. Without my addition the program works fine without any issues on all our regression machines, on our products and on my PC. Also, as mentioned it works most of the time. For example, while in a loop, it works couple of times before it crashes.

Comment: Regarding 2: For brevity I chose the IDs as 1,2,3, ... etc. But in reality, they are actual GUIDs. An example: const guid_typ one = {0x8654D7AD};

Comment: Just because without addtition "the program works fine without any issues" doesn't mean that it's bug free. C++ has no such guarantees. It'll only take me a little bit of time to come up with some code that overwrites something, but runs fine until I add some function somewhere else entirely, that subtly changes the memory allocation order, and everything comes crashing down. There's nothing in the shown code that should result in undefined behavior, a.k.a. bug. Therefore the bug must be in the code that's not shown. Welcome to C++. That's why you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes I agree with you. Unfortunately my attempts to generate a reproducible code failed. The reason for my emphatic "works without any issues" is: As mentioned, I am calling the static func. in the debugger watch window, and not in the run-time code. And I call the function 'RI_NAME' at multiple places of the program where I want to know the item I am dealing with. So the issue is not localized to one place/function/source file. If you see no obvious undefined behavior, as I do too, could that be that calling such static functions is corrupting the program stack ?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with calling static functions, in this manner.